# What is the role of Josephson junctions and biases in the D-Wave qubit structure?

Tags: experimental-realization, d-wave, superconducting-quantum-computing

On the D-Wave 2000Q there are up to 2048 qubits and 5600 coupler. A commonly used picture of one of such qubits is attached below.

Each qubit is realized by a loop of niobium controlled by Josephson junctions and biases represented by $\Phi$’s. As far as I know couplers are also realized by simpler niobium loops.

Clear to me is: That the direction of current in the loop corresponds to the state of the qubit. And that the qubit can be placed in superposition (current running in both directions) when supercooled.

Now I've gathered some questions all regarding the structure and function of such qubit and/or coupler.

- What exactly is the role of the Josephson junction in the qubit? They don't seem to be attached to something.
- Why is a double loop used instead of a single loop (and a single Josephson junction)?
- How are the $\Phi$'s build? And more importantly what is their role in the qubit structure?
- How is a qubit read out after the annealing process? (Is there some connection to the $\Phi$'s?)

[image: qubit on D-Wave System]